# Creating the multiplication table

Tags: python, multiplication

I'm trying to create a multiplication table. The user enters their list of numbers and the program spits out the multiplication for each number. for example,

```
3 x 1 = 3
3 x 2= 6 
3 x 3 = 9
......
.....
3 x 12=42
```

this is what I have tried so far:

```
enter code here
N = int(input("How many numbers would you like to multiply?:"))
num = []
q=1
p = 1
count=0



for i in range(0,N):
 add = int(input(f"number {i}:"))
 num.append(add)
 print(num)



for j in num:
     while q <= 12:
         print (j * q, end=" ")
         q+=1

#The result is 
How many numbers would you like to multiply?:3
number 0:2
number 1:6
number 2:5
[2, 6, 5]
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 
enter code here
```

How do I get the program to spit out all the multiplication for every number in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Store your tables in a dictionary and call in any way you want. See below code:

```
def inputmethod():
    N = int(input("How many numbers would you like to multiply?:"))
    num = []
    for i in range(0,N):
        add = int(input(f"number {i}:"))
        num.append(add)
    return num

def multiplication(m,num):
    L = list(range(1,m+1))
    dict_tables = {}
    for n in num:
        dict_tables[n] = [e*n for e in L]
    return dict_tables

def print_tables(dict_tables):
    for key,value in dict_tables.items():
        print(f"Table of {key} is : {value}")

num = inputmethod()
generate_tables = multiplication(12,num)
print_tables(generate_tables)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how (and why) I would have written that:

```
# More verbose variable names are nice documentation!
num_count = int(input("How many numbers would you like to multiply?:"))

numbers = []
# Start at 1 instead of 0, because humans are used to counting from 1.
for i in range(1, num_count + 1):
    number = int(input(f"number {i}:"))
    numbers.append(number)

print(numbers)

# Loop across the list of numbers you built in the previous step.
for number in numbers:
    # `for i in range(...)` is the canonical Python way to loop over numbers.
    for i in range(1, 13):
        print(number * i, end=" ")

    print()
```

Alternatively:

```
...
   for i in range(12):
       print(number * (i + 1), end=" ")
...
```

gets the same result, but I find it a lot simpler to iterate over the actual list of numbers I want to use, *especially* in more complex formulas where you're referring to that variable more than once. For instance, if you were calculating squares and writing `number * (i + 1) * (i + 1)`, and you were my coworker, I would wag my finger at you.